# "JRoute::_" generating two different urls for same link

Tags: menu, jroute

So I have this weird problem.

I am calling

```
JRoute::_('index.php?option=com_example&view=foo&layout=bar')
```

..from two different `view-layouts`. And Joomla! is generating different SEF-URL based on **which layout that I am calling the above code from**.

*What I expect is that, If I generate an SEF URL it should point to that same exact resource with same exact URL, no matter where I am calling this from, since everything is pretty specific. viz. the component name, the view name, and the layout name.*

Comment: Have you built a router for your component?

Answer (score 0):

You need to build router for your component read moere about here:
https://docs.joomla.org/J3.x:Supporting_SEF_URLs_in_your_component

Comment: Link-only answers are low value on all Stack Exchange sites because if the link location dies or us moves, then your answer is rendered useless to researchers.  Please always write the bulk of your suggested solution as the major portion of your answer.  Providing a link to documentation is of course a good idea -- so don't delete it when you write your edit.